# How can we set a limit to the results came in @POST request in retrofit android

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am trying to retrieve data from a web api in jSON format using retrofit. The result returns 5 items where it has 20 items. I need to show top 10 items. So is there any way to set a limit to the no. of results to retrieve?

The interface for http request looks like this:

```
public interface TestService {
@POST("apiUrl")
Call<APIRespone> TestByType(@Body TestRequest request);
```

}

Comment: This is not a case for `Retrofit`. Try looking for a specified option in the API specification.

Comment: You have to custom the web api to do this

Comment: You can use Retrofit 2.0 that supports dynamic url parameters. you can add pagination support like page number, offset and limits per page. check this link by jake wharton : https://realm.io/news/droidcon-jake-wharton-simple-http-retrofit-2/

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your API, if it allows you to set Pagination you might be able to set the number of items returned by the server. Double check you API documentation if it is a standard one you will have pagination.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed that issue by changing the value of a limit variable at the server side where the json response is returned to the API call. I thought that there would be some issue with my retrofit code but it wasn't. Thank you all who have commented above. You are all helped me to solve it.